# Unable to rake db on Heroku (One Month Rails class)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migrate

I am working through the One Month Rails class with Mattan Griffel and I was having an issue with Imagemagik (getting the following error when trying to upload a photo with a style applied in pin.rb - xzy image not recognized by the 'identify' command) and saw on another post that this issue had to do with Imagemagik install on my local machine and that the application should work (with uploading pins in the correct size) when deployed to Heroku. So, I went back and updated my github and pushed the master to Heroku. When running the db migration I got the following error:

`PG::Error: ERROR: relation "pins" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "pins" ADD COLUMN "user_id" integer`

It looks like the pins relation doesn't even exist? Before debugging the issue with Imagemagik I'd love to get the application running on Heroku. Any thoughts?

Github - https://github.com/jrlundberg/omrails
Application - http://still-scrubland-2791.herokuapp.com/

Thanks!

Jason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your migration `20130319034336` you are trying to add a `user_id` column to a table `pins` that does not exist. Change the migration to:

```
class AddUserIdToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pins do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :pins, :user_id
  end
end
```